# Concatenating data including leading zero's mid lot number not working

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to concatenate data from multiple places in my spreadsheet to make a final lot number.

- I have a value of C54 which is a constant,
- Then a number that increases every cycle (this can only ever be 2 digits, starting with "01") - when this number reaches 99 it will go back to 01
- Then another constant is LA

The first lot number would look like this "C5401LA"

Currently my code looks like this:

```
ActiveCell.Value = "C54" & Sequencer.Range("F7") & "LA"
```

However this does not keep my leading zero required between lots 01 - 09.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Format` wrapper to force it to two digits.

```
ActiveCell.Value = "C54" & Format(Sequencer.Range("F7"),"00") & "LA"
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked exactly as I needed!